# How can I save rich text format data using asp.net in database ? How to retrieve the same data in a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, rtf

How can I save rich text format data using asp.net in database ? How to retrieve the same data in a gridview ?

I am trying to the take the input using texteditor provided in bootstrap framework.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet.. I was just googling around and found few third party plugins, but I want something which can be done without a third party plugin.

Comment: You can directly save innerHTML of your texteditor into database, all you need to set  `ValidateRequest="false"`   in @Page line on your web page

Comment: This property will be applied to all the forms in that page. Is it ok to have this page directive set for all other items in the page ? will it hamper normal behaviour of other items in the page ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this question. One easy way for a begginner is to use Editor control in Ajax Control toolkit bundle. Editor control can be used like most of the other controls are used from the Ajax Control Toolkit(ACT) bundle. You need to add the ScriptManager from ACT bundle for the Editor control to work.

Helpful link : [Online Demo and Documentation of the Control]

The saved value can be fetched and binded into a label control or even a gridview to view on the webpage.